# Maximize the volume of a cone

Tags: derivatives

How do I maximize the volume of a cone which is inscribed inside a sphere of radius $r$. I know that $V=\pi r^2h$. But how do you inscribe that into a sphere with radius $r$.

Comment: You're confusing yourself because you're using the same variable $r$ to refer to both the radius of the sphere and the radius of the cone. But the radius of a maximal volume inscribed cone need to be the same as the radius of the sphere. (It may turn out to be, but we can't see that from the outset.)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, once you let the radius of the cone's base be a different variable (say $r$) than the radius of the sphere (say $R$), then all you need to do is come up with a formula for $r$ in terms of $R$ and $h$.  Hint: think about the relationship between $(h-R)$ and $r$.

Answer (score 1):

$V = \dfrac{π r^2 h}{3}$

And that of a sphere of radio $R$: $V = \dfrac{4π R^3}{3} $

The problem can be reduced to two dimensions considering the case of a circle centered on the origin of coordinates and radius $R$ that has inscribed a triangle of base $2r$ and height $R + a$, where $``a"$ is variable.

When both lines are rotated around the $X$-axis, they describe a sphere with an inscribed cone of radius $R$ and $r$ respectively and cone height $h = R + a$:

It is necessary to maximize the volume of the cone with the condition that it is inscribed in the sphere, that is, to maximize the function:
$V (a, r) ​​= \dfrac{πr^2 (R + a)}{ 3}$.
Provided that the point $(a, r)$ ​​belongs to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$, that is, that the relation is fulfilled:

$a^2 + r^2 = R^2$

$r^2 = R^2 - a^2 ........... (1)$

And substituting in the formula of the volume of the cone we have eliminated the variable $"r"$ and it remains:

$V (a) = \dfrac{π (R^2 - a^2) (R + a)}{3} = \dfrac{π (R^3 + aR^2 - a^2 R - a^2)}{3}$

Let's see for what value of "a" said volume is maximum. Deriving and equating to zero:

$V'(a) = \dfrac{π(R^2-2aR-3a^2)} { 3}  = 0$

$R^2-2aR-3a^2 = 0\Rightarrow 3a^2+2aR-R^2 = 0$

Quadratic equation in "a", which by the resolvent leaves us

$a = \dfrac{-2R \pm \sqrt{4R^2 + 12 R^2}}{6} $

whose two roots are:

$a_1 = \dfrac{- 2R + 4R}{6} = \dfrac{R}{3}$

$a_2 = \dfrac{- 2R - 4R} {6} = - R$

Taking the only possible value, the positive one, i.e $a_1$, we substitute it in equation (1), we have left

$r^2 = R^2 - \dfrac{R^2}{9} = \dfrac{8R^2}{9}$

That is, the maximum volume of the cone inscribed in the sphere of radius R is obtained for a conical radius:

$R = \dfrac{\sqrt{8R^2}}{3} = \dfrac{2R \sqrt{2}}{3}$

And for a cone height of:

$h = R + a = R + \dfrac{R}{3} = \dfrac{4R}{3}$

The maximum volume of the inscribed cone will therefore be:

$V = π (\dfrac{8R^2}{9})(\dfrac{4R}{3}) = \dfrac{32 πR^3}{81}$